# Iterating over very long lines in a huge file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to iterate over log files in a linux environment using a shell script. Here is my code:

```
while read p; do
 head=${p:0:250}
 #some code here#
done < ./log.txt
```

I am taking only the first 250 chars into a variable to process it in the loop. The lines in the log file can be huge and the file itself is almost 5 GB. When I run the above code on a few sample lines, I get the following error:

```
 xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562068080 bytes (36864 bytes allocated)
```

Is there a way I can get only a part of the line instead of the whole line while iterating? or is there any other better way of achieving what I am trying to do?

**EDIT:**
When I run the script with `-x` , I see that the script is stopping at `read p` for a while and then I get the error message. I think it is trying to load the whole line before proceeding and that is causing the issue.

I am assigning the first 250 chars to a variable(`$head`) so that I can later split that variable into an array and do some operations while iterating over that array. I don't need the variable as long as I can access the first 250 chars from the line.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: may be we could skip assigning variable part, in case you could let us know what actually you are trying to do here?

Comment: added the information to the question. Thanks! @RavinderSingh13

Comment: after assignment of variable what you are trying to do, we could may be skip it and do our tasks without it.

Comment: When I run the script with `-x` , I see that the script is stopping at `read p` for a while and then I get the error message. I think it is trying to load the whole line before proceeding and that is causing the issue. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: A quick way out of this might be, `cut -c -250 ./log.txt | while read head; do ...; done`. However, as @RavinderSingh13 mentioned. we might help you out better if we know what `#some code here` exactly does.

Comment: You can easily read only 250 bytes with `read -n 250`, but the problem is that it doesn't leave the file pointer at the start of the next line, but rather leaves it 250 bytes into your very long line.

Comment: @kvantour, I'd suggest `while IFS= read -r head; do ...; done < <(cut -c -250 ./log.txt)` instead; that way you avoid the bug described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) (the reasons for `IFS=` and `-r` are discussed in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)).

Comment: thanks for the comment @CharlesDuffy . I tried it doing the way you suggested and I see the script is working now! Please post your comment as an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cutting content down to the first 250 characters of each line is best done before getting into the shell loop. You can do that, while still retaining state from variables set within the loop, via [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r p; do
  : put your code for processing "$p" here
done < <(cut -c -250 ./log.txt)
```

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) discussing the reasons for `IFS=` and `read -r`, and [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more details on why process substitution is beneficial here.